# Firebase - different package name and app id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have problem with FCM push notifications. I implemented everything as it's described in docs. However it doesn't work. I believe it's because of difference between app id and package name in manifest file.

Lets say my app id is

```
com.xyz.tycoon
```

and exactly this id is added in Firebase. However , in manifest file package name is like this :

```
package="com.xyz.app"
```

I believe this is the reason why push notifications don't work. How can I fix it ? I don't want to add another project to Firebase cause I already have a lots of data there. Any ideas, please ?

Comment: Can't u change the package in manifest?

Comment: No, app is not compiling then.

Comment: Use `flavor` matching with firebase app id

Answer (score 0):

To change the package name:

Right click on your package folder under the project structure window in android studio -> Refactor -> Rename

And so you have now updated your package name.

Comment: it's not so easy , I have a lot of submodules and modules that are connected with each other.

Comment: refactor will take care of it. hd the same problem. Solved it using this method. If you want use the solution or else let by

Answer (score 0):

No need to change package name. Use `productFlavors` to sync your app with firebase matching app id. Update your module level `build.gradle` like below:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId('com.xyz.app')

    ....
}

productFlavors {
    appProd {
        applicationId 'com.xyz.tycoon'

        ....
    }
}
```

Check [official doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#product-flavors) to configure `productFlavors`

Comment: It will force users to install second version of the app on the device, correct ?

Comment: When you release the app or build for debug, use `appProd` flavor to bundle the apk. Then the APK configured with `com.xyz.tycoon` package name without changes the internal structure